# How to make a Search Bar that looks for buttons

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to make a **Flow Layout Panel** and fill it with a bunch of buttons. I want to have a Text box on the top of the form to search for a specific button. No clue on how. When the user searches, all other buttons will not be visible, only the button that its .text property matches will be visible.

Comment: what are the search criteria? Button text? What do you want to happen when you find the button? Tempted to vote to put on hold as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming search box is looking for the button's `.Text` property, that the textbox is named `txtSearch`, and the panel is named `pnlButtons`:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    pnlButtons.SuspendLayout()

    For Each c As Control In pnlButtons.Controls
       c.Visible = False
    Next

    Dim matchingButtons = pnlButtons.Controls.OfType(Of Button).Where(Function(b) b.Text.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text))
    For Each b As Button In matchingButtons
         b.Visible = True
     Next 

     pnlButtons.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I hide all the buttons that do not match the text that is searched?

Comment: I have also wonder if each searched button could be lessened by each character typed. Meaning each button with abs would be shown and as the user keeps typing the buttons match the text typed, but not worrying about UPPER or lower case.

Comment: That work 100%, but how can I just make the buttons be eliminated (not visible) depending on what character is typed in, not exactly matching the txtSearch.text.. Example) the buttons I have are: <H1> <head> <H2> <Link> ect. and I type in txtSearch " <H " then stop typing. And <link> should be gone because it does not match <H. If i keep typing and type " <He " or " <he " and stop typing, <head> should be the only one visible or any button with " <HE " not matching case.